# How to ensure two classes in two threads writing same variable thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have two classes running in 2 threads in the same time, say class `A` and class `B`, `A` is collecting data from some API and keep pushing updated data into an `unordered-map` as `B->m`. In the same time `B` is using the data to create a custom class `Bar`, code is like this:

**Class `A`:**

```
if(m.size() > 0){
//mtx.lock();
lock = B->lock;
if(lock == false){
  lock = true;
  B->m = m;     
  lock = false;
}    
m.clear();
//mtx.unlock();
}
```

**Class `B`:**

```
 while(true){
    if(m.size() > 0){
        //mtx.lock();
        if(lock == false){
            lock = true;
            for (auto it : m) {
              std::string symbol = it.first;
              std::vector<double> v = it.second;
              Bar b;
              b.open = v[0];
              b.high = v[1];                
              bars.push_back(b);
            }
            m.clear();

            lock = false;
        }
        //mtx.unlock();
    }}
```

As can be seen here, I have tried manually implemented a mutex by using a boolean called `lock`, when I compile sometimes it finishes sometimes seg fault, which I think is because of edge case: when I set `lock` to `true` in class `B`, class `A` has just skipped `if(lock == false)` and `B` is reading data that's changing by `A`. My question is, how to avoid that happen?

Comment: Manual mutex implementation won't work. Just don't. Use proper mutex object from pthread or `std::mutex` if C++1x.

Comment: @ freakish if I use std::mutex, where should I put mutex.lock()? see the comment code above, I tried it but didn't work because it's mutex in two classes

Comment: Don't use `mutex.lock()` at all. It is not exception safe. Use `std::lock_guard` inside a block of code. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manual mutex implementation won't work (at least not in an easy way). For example from the compiler point of view this

```
lock = strategy->lock;
if(lock == false){
  lock = true;
  B->m = m;     
  lock = false;
}
```

can be rearanged into this

```
lock = strategy->lock;
if(lock == false){
  B->m = m;
}
```

because the single threaded outcome (which is the compilers default point of view if you don't tell it otherwise) is exactly the same.

There are also other reasons that it may fail, like for example partial object filling. Generally complex stuff.

So you have to use some synchronization object that the library you are using is providing you with. For C++11 and higher you can simply use [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex):

```
#include <mutex>
std::mutex my_mutex;
...

// some code
{
    // lock resource
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(my_mutex);
    B->m = m;
}
// automatically releases the lock and continues the execution
```

Comment: should I put lock_guard in class B as well? in my code, only A is writing m of B, B is just reading its m, so no writing for B.

Comment: @ZixuanZhang Well, that depends on the whole code. But generally you need a lock_guard in B as well. Simply because you may end up reading an invalid memory, because some other thread will destroy the underlying B->m while setting it to a new value (hence segfault from the reader).

Answer (score 1):

You need std::mutex and std::condition_variable.

`std::mutex` for protecting your code from undefined behavior and `std::condition_variable` for informing worker threads that there are work(s) need to be done.

If you really want to implement yourself a mutex, then make sure that you are using atomic types, such as `std::atomic_flag`, `std::atomic<bool>` etc..

---

Implementing yourself a "thread-safe" container is an easy option for your problem here, it will be something like (not tested yet, just for looking):

```
#include <mutex>
#include <utility>
#include <unordered_map>

template <class Value, class Key>
class Container {
 public:
  bool Get(const Key &key, Value &value) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtx_);
    auto ite = mp_.find(key);
    if (ite == mp_.end())
      return false;

    value = std::move(ite->second);
    mp_.erase(ite);
    return true;
  }

  template <class ValueType>
  void Insert(const Key &key, ValueType &&value) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtx_);
    mp_[key] = std::forward<ValueType>(value);
  }
private:
  std::unordered_map<Value, Key> mp_; 
  std::mutex mtx_;
};
```

There are lots of things you need to pay attention to when implementing concurrency algorithm, I suggest you to read some books concerning this topic first(Don't worry, you will learn them the hard way anyway). "C++ concurrency in action" is a good start.